# AspectJ Pointcut for methods taking any number arguments of types Serializable or primitive type

Tags: java, aspectj, pointcut

How would I write a Pointcut for methods taking any number of arguments that either implements Serializable or are of primitive type?

E.g. Pointcut should match:

```
methodA(String str, int i)
methodB(String str, String str2, List<String> list)
```

but not

```
methodC(String str, DataX data)
```

where DataX is not Serializable

Comment: Do you also need methods with zero arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way I know of to specify that kind of condition in a pointcut, so the only thing I have for you is quite expensive because it involves runtime checks - but it does what you want:

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Application {
    public static class MyNonSerializable {}

    public static class MySerializable implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }

    private static MyNonSerializable one() {
        return new MyNonSerializable();
    }

    static MySerializable two(int i, String string) {
        return new MySerializable();

    }

    static String three(int i, String string, MyNonSerializable myNonSerializable) {
        return "foo";
    }

    static MyNonSerializable four(int i, String string, MySerializable mySerializable) {
        return new MyNonSerializable();
    }

    static void five(MyNonSerializable myNonSerializable) {
    }

    static int six(MySerializable mySerializable) {
        return 11;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        one();
        two(11, "foo");
        three(11, "foo", new MyNonSerializable());
        four(11, "foo", new MySerializable());
        five(new MyNonSerializable());
        six(new MySerializable());
    }
}
```

Now, regardless of the return type, we want to intercept executions with either zero arguments or any number of `Serializable` arguments. The methods conforming to this condition are `main`, `one`, `two`, `four`, `six`.

**Aspect with runtime type checking:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.io.Serializable;

public aspect MethodsWithSerializableArgumentsAspect {
    before() : execution(* *(..)) {
        boolean nonSerializableArgumentFound = false;
        for (Object arg : thisJoinPoint.getArgs()) {
            if (!(arg == null || arg instanceof Serializable)) {
                nonSerializableArgumentFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nonSerializableArgumentFound)
            return;
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
execution(Application.MyNonSerializable de.scrum_master.app.Application.one())
execution(Application.MySerializable de.scrum_master.app.Application.two(int, String))
execution(Application.MyNonSerializable de.scrum_master.app.Application.four(int, String, Application.MySerializable))
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.six(Application.MySerializable))
```

Tadaa! `:-)`

Now if you also want to exclude methods returning non-serializable objects, that should limit the output to `main`, `two`, `six`. You can do it like this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.io.Serializable;

public aspect MethodsWithSerializableArgumentsAspect {
    Object around() : execution(* *(..)) {
        boolean nonSerializableArgumentFound = false;
        for (Object arg : thisJoinPoint.getArgs()) {
            if (!(arg instanceof Serializable)) {
                nonSerializableArgumentFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        Object result = proceed();
        if ((result == null || result instanceof Serializable) && !nonSerializableArgumentFound)
            System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(Application.MySerializable de.scrum_master.app.Application.two(int, String))
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.six(Application.MySerializable))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
```

Please note that in order to do a runtime check on the return value, we can only print the result *after* the method has terminated. Thus, `main` is at the end of the log output, not at the beginning as in the first solution.

**Update:** I forgot to explain why we need to check aruments and return value for `null`. This is because we want to accept `null` or `void` as `Serializable`, but actually `null instanceof Serializable` is false.

---

**Update 2 - static pointcut solution without runtime type checks:**

Okay, I was just eating an apple (no, it did not fall onto my head) and suddenly had this idea. It actually works nicely and is exactly what you want:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.io.Serializable;

public aspect MethodsWithSerializableArgumentsAspect {
    pointcut returnsSerializable() :
        execution((Serializable+ || byte || short || int || long || float || double || char || boolean || void) *(..));

    pointcut hasNonSerializableArguments() :
        execution(* *(.., !(Serializable+ || byte || short || int || long || float || double || char || boolean || void), ..));

    before() : returnsSerializable() && !hasNonSerializableArguments() {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

BTW, `Serializable+` means "Serializable and all of its subclasses or implementing classes".

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. This works fine indeed, but I was hoping it was possible to express entirely in the Pointcut. But as you said, it might not be possible...

Comment: Check out my update for the perfect solution with static pointcut, no more runtime checks now. :)))